# How to search for a term within subfolders in HDFS recursively?

Tags: hadoop, grep, hdfs

I want to be able to search for a pattern of string inside all the sub-directories and files in specific directory in HDFS. This is how it looks like -

hadoop fs -ls /MARCH24/

`drwxrwxr-x user supergroup 0 00:59 2022-03-24 March24-00`

`drwxrwxr-x user supergroup 0 01:59 2022-03-24 March24-01`

`drwxrwxr-x user supergroup 0 02:59 2022-03-24 March24-02`

`drwxrwxr-x user supergroup 0 03:59 2022-03-24 March24-03`

`drwxrwxr-x user supergroup 0 04:59 2022-03-24 March24-04`

How do i search through all these subdirectories for a term like user or customer?
My search query doesn't work

hadoop fs -cat -R /MARCH24/* | grep -i -e user -e customer

Answer (score 0):

The Unix command to **find** files is named `find`. You didn't provide any sample input/output so we can't do more than suggest this:

```
find /MARCH24 -type f -exec grep -iE 'user|customer' {} +
```

and if that's not what you want then see the `find` and `grep` man pages.